# How to place all array values to a column of text fields in order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, html-table, fill

Well, I have a table consisting of rows and columns and one of these columns consists of all text fields, and if there is also an array that has values, how can these values be placed in all the text fields for this column in order?

```js
const row = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
let numberOfColumns;
const marks = [2, 5, 7, 6, 4, 9]
row.forEach(( item ) => {
    const columnsOfInput = item.querySelectorAll(["td > input"]);
    numberOfColumns = columnsOfInput.length
    for (let i = 0; i < columnsOfInput.length; i++) {
        for (let mark in marks) {
            columnsOfInput[ 0 ].value = mark.slice()
/*
All fields will be filled with number 5, meaning the array length, but this is not the goal!
How to place all values of "marks" array to all fields in order 2, 5, 7, 6, 4, 9 ?
*/
        }
    }
});
console.log(`number of columns: ${numberOfColumns}`); //  all columns that has text fields
```

```html
<body>
<table style="width:50%; text-align: center">

<tr>
    <th>Mark1</th>
    <th>Mark2</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>


</table>

   
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do something similar to this:

```
const row = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
let numberOfColumns, marksIndex = -1;
const marks = [2, 5, 7, 6, 4, 9]

row.forEach(( item) => {    
    const columnsOfInput = item.querySelectorAll(["td > input"]);
    numberOfColumns = columnsOfInput.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < columnsOfInput.length; i++) { 
        for(let mark in marks){
            columnsOfInput[i].value = marks[marksIndex];     
        }   
    }

    marksIndex++;
});
```

This should get you the 5 rows that you coded in your HTML and have the value 2 in Mark1 and Mark2, then 5 in Mark1 and Mark2, etc...

If this is not what you were going for let me know and I will try to assist again.